# wordpress search word, “hello world” ===> ‘hello+world’ ===> ‘hello’, ‘world’

Tags: wp-query, functions, search, code

I need a Function Code to improve the wordpress search engine

For example, if the user searched: `Hello world`

First, the results of `Hello + World` are searched

and the next results: `Hello` and `world`

and the next results: `Hello` or`world`

without plugin

Comment: Is there any reason why you are asking the same question again and again with very small variations and under different accounts? You have been told already that you have to share your research efforts and your own code. Tip: Improve one of your existing questions. That works much better than re-asking. :)

Comment: Why does not anyone know the answer?

Comment: As @fuxia has said above. Share your own research efforts and provide your own code that you have tried already.

Why can't you use a plugin?

Comment: I've improved almost all the WordPress search engine, but I do not find any code for this feature, I just know I have to add a code to function,
I already had such a code but I'm not currently available